Add a close button to tabs
I am learning bootstrap, and I want to have an x next to each tab name to close it:


<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item" id="tab-li-1">
    <button
      class="nav-link active"
      data-bs-toggle="tab"
      data-bs-target="#tab-1"
      type="button"
    >
      First
      <button
        class="btn-close"
        onclick="
          document.getElementById(`tab-li-1`).remove();
          document.getElementById(`tab-1`).remove();
        "
       ></button>
    </button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" id="tab-li-2">
    <button
      class="nav-link"
      data-bs-toggle="tab"
      data-bs-target="#tab-2"
      type="button"
     >
     Second
       <button
        class="btn-close"
        onclick="
          document.getElementById(`tab-li-2`).remove();
          document.getElementById(`tab-2`).remove();
        "
       ></button>
     </button>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="tab-1" tabindex="0">Some text here for `First`</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab-2" tabindex="0">More text here for `Second`</div>
</div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



I was able to hack something around nesting another button inside my first button and then:
document.getElementById(tabId).remove();
document.getElementById(tabContentId).remove();

but I have found online that it is not valid to nest a button inside another button
Is there a better alternative that people can suggest?

What do you mean with close? do you want to hide all content then? Why not simply create a tab that has no content? You can not nest interactive elements into each other. There will be no easy way to solve this.

I think he meant tabs like chrome tab where you can click the tab to focus it, but there's also a close button to kill it

@tacoshy I mean close as in removing the tab. I have made an edit to the snippet to show how I got something working nesting buttons.

Why would those buttons need to be nested? If you just make them two separate buttons, it still renders the same as it currently does - because the browser's error correction algorithm already made two separate buttons out of your incorrectly nested HTML, as can be clearly seen when inspecting the resulting DOM.

@CBroe Hmm, I want the x to be next the the tab name. The only way I got that working was nesting the button inside the other button. I will check my actual code to see if I have something else that is different. For some reason it looks OK in my code, but not in the snippet here.

You don't need to nest buttons. You don't have to use a buttons for your tabs and can just use a normal div. For accessibility reasons, you should use role="button" therefor.
Instead of hardcoding the buttons you could simply use JS to create the close buttons on every tab.
Your script should remove not only the tab itself but also the connected tab-pane:


window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const TABS = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link');

  //adds clsoe button to all tabs
  TABS.forEach(tab => {
    let closeBtn = document.createElement('button');
    closeBtn.ariaLabel = 'Close Button';
    closeBtn.textContent = 'X';
    closeBtn.addEventListener('click', removeTab); 
    tab.appendChild(closeBtn);
  })
  
  //removes the tab and the tab-pane
  function removeTab() {
    let tabId = this.closest('.nav-link').dataset.bsTarget;
    let tabPaneElement = document.querySelector(tabId);
    let liElement = this.closest('li');
    tabPaneElement.remove();
    liElement.remove();
  }
})
.nav-link {
  &:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  button {
    margin-left: 1em;
  }
}
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item" id="tab-li-1">
    <div class="nav-link active" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#tab-1" role="button">First</div>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <div class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#tab-2" role="button">Second</div>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="tab-1" tabindex="0">Some text here for `First`</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab-2" tabindex="0">More text here for `Second`</div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>




Oh, something I noticed with using div is that moving the mouse on top of the tab doesn't look the same way as it does for a button. I don't know how to explain it properly. If I move my mouse on top of a button it becomes a little hand. That doesn't happen in this case. Is there a way to keep that behaviour?

what do you mean? It does perfectly in this example. Maybe your Browser is outdated and does not support nesting CSS yet.
